# Trying to convert ArrayList to Array, but IDE "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this ArrayList of Animal objects:

```
ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
animals.add(new Animal(1, "animal1", 50, "10 Janvier 2016", "Noir", 4, true));
animals.add(new Animal(2, "animal2", 40, "10 Janvier 2016", "Noir", 4, true));
```

I'm trying to create a method of conversion of this ArrayList into an Array. So far i've come up with :

```
public Animal[] tArray(){
    return animals.toArray();
}
```

But my IDE says he can't find the symbol variable animals.

How could i transform my ArrayList animals into an array ?

Edit : i think my problem isn't related to the method itself but more the structure of the code into my class.

Comment: @CubeJockey It's different: OP tries to do something else.

Comment: I think the code is correct (using a toArray); the problem i meet tho is about variable recognition.

Comment: your IDE cannot find `animals` it is likely you have it declared out of scope. Is it a class variable?

Comment: @CubeJockey Yes, but it is a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert a local variable to an array inside an instance method. This is not going to work, because local variables are, well, local to methods or constructors in which they are declared.

You need to do one of the following:

- Declare a field `private List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();` and remove `animals` local variable, or
- Declare an array field `private Animal[] animalArray`, and assign it right after making the `animals` local; getter would then return `aninalsArray`.

Comment: Thanks; i know declared my ArrayList<Animal> animals outside the main function.

Yet my function Animal[] toArray() { return animals.toArray(); } is still not functionnal. Maybe you have a clue on what i'm missing ?

I have an error "incompatible types"

Comment: @AodRen Incompatible types can be fixed by `animals.toArray(new Animal[animals.size()])`

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
public static Animal[] toArray(ArrayList<Animal> animals){
    return animals == null ? null : animals.toArray(new Animal[animals.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Don't code dump answers, it helps nobody learn from their mistakes. At least give some explanation

Comment: This also won't fix OPs problem